# How to enable rememberme on tapestry-security

Tags: security, tapestry, remember-me

Environment: tapestry 5.4.3, tapestry-security 0.7.1.

I have a working configuration that secure some pages doing login if necessary, all is working as expected, what is not working if the rememberme feature when at login I select the rememberme check box. I did not configure SecuritySymbols.REMEMBERME_CIPHERKERY because it defaults to HMAC_PASSPHRASE, but I can confirm there is not security related messages or errors on log, I am sure that rememberme cookies are being send to browser with 1 year lifespan, and that the browser is sending the cookie back to server on different browser sessions.

Can somebody help me with a full working example ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the filter chains, I had something like this on AppModule.java:

```
configuration.add("proveedores", factory.createChain("/proveedores").add(factory.authc()).build());
```

But the correct one is:

```
configuration.add("proveedores", factory.createChain("/proveedores").add(factory.user()).build());
```

Because user is the filter that allows a remembered user to use the resouces under the indicated path.

I hope this help others.